# How do I get the list of imports and dependant files from python script?

Tags: python

I have a .py file that imports from other python modules that import from config files, other modules, etc.

I am to move the code needed to run that .py file, but only whatever the py file is reading from (I am not talking about packages installed by pip install, it's more about other python files in the project directory, mostly classes, functions and ini files).

Is there a way to find out only the external files used by that particular python script? Is it something that can be found using PyCharm for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Static analysis tools (such as PyCharm's refactoring tools) can (mostly) figure out the module import tree for a program (unless you do dynamic imports using e.g. `importlib.import_module()`).

However, it's not quite possible to statically definitively know what other files are required for your program to function. You could use Python's audit events (or `strace`/`ptrace` or similar OS-level functions) to look at what files are being opened by your program (e.g. during your tests being run (you do have tests, right?), or during regular program use), but it's likely not going to be exhaustive.